# I can't export my combined BIBTEXT file for biblioshiny()

Tags: r, bibtex, biblatex

Hello I'm using R for this, this is my code and I'm trying to export this.

`library (bibliometrix)`

I retrive some data

`web_data <- convert2df("D:/OECM articles/Marine/WOB_dets.bib", dbsource= "wos",format="bibtex")`

`Scopus_data<- convert2df ("D:/OECM articles/Marine/Scopus_dets.bib", dbsource= "scopus", format="bibtex")`

Then I combined them

`combined1 <- mergeDbSources(web_data,Scopus_data, remove.duplicated = T)`

`colnames(combined1) <-colnames(combined1)[2:ncol(combined1)]`

`head(combined1)`

`write_xlsx(combined1,"(combined1.xlsx")`

then this happens

`Error in libxlsxwriter: 'String exceeds Excel's limit of 32,767 characters.'

this is what happens when I run the code, I tried exporting the combined1 to bibtex it didn't want to read in biblioshiny() and I tried CSV but it also didn't work its format is weird

Thank you all in advanced

Answer (score 0):

> `Error in libxlsxwriter: 'String exceeds Excel's limit of 32,767 characters.'

Excel has a limit of 32,767 characters per cell. It looks like there is one of more entries in your dataframe that exceeds that limit.

If possible, and it makes sense, you should truncate the dataframe strings to less than that limit. Otherwise you won't be able to store the strings in Excel.